# Error in including boost tokenizer.hpp file when building R package on MacOS/CRAN

Tags: r, boost, rcpp, r-package

I'm running into issues publishing my R package to CRAN, because of a specific error when including boost libraries. The top of my one .cpp file in the package is

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <omp.h>
#include <vector>

// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]
```

When running through the check on MacOS (via `rhub::check(platform = "macos-highsierra-release-cran")`, I get the following error:

> In file included from wgt_jaccard.cpp:6:
> /Users/user2suimGYX/R/BH/include/boost/tokenizer.hpp:63:9: error: field of type 'std::_*1::**wrap_iter<const char *>' has private constructor
> : first*(c.begin()), last*(c.end()), f*(f) { }
> ^

> wgt_jaccard.cpp:117:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char, std::__1::char_traits >, std::__1::__wrap_iter<const char *>, std::__1::basic_string ::tokenizer<Rcpp::internal::string_proxy<16, PreserveStorage> >' requested here
> tokenizer tokens(y(i), sep);
> ^

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iterator:1420:31: note: declared private here
> _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY __wrap_iter(iterator_type __x) _NOEXCEPT_DEBUG : __i(__x) {}
> ^

My Makevars file's contents are

```
PKG_CXXFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS) -DBOOST_NO_AUTO_PTR
PKG_LIBS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)
CXX_STD = CXX11
```

I've tried searching around, but can't find much on this error. The full package is located [here](https://github.com/seunglee98/fedmatch). Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I would try to make a smaller problem.  Create a one-off throw-away package just doing the tokenizer, and get that to build on macOS via RHub.  Maybe is header-file order, maybe it is something -- but _something_ is different from where I built this happily with `g++` on Linux.

Comment: I took another look -- it has to do with the templated instantiation of `tokenizer` which rubs `clang++` in a different way that `g++`.  A usual remedy is to go first your element of `Rcpp::StringVector` to a plain `std::string` have Boost chew on that.  I'll send you a PR in a bit.

Comment: See here:  https://github.com/seunglee98/fedmatch/pull/2

Comment: Thanks a ton! This solved it. Feel free to submit a full answer and I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Good suggestion, and now done.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. Feel free to also upvote it (as I did with your question) (unless your total karma of (currently) 13 prevents you from doing so, I keep forgetting what "them rules" are here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relative to [the repo](https://github.com/seunglee98/fedmatch) you kindly supplied, we found a need for two changes:

First, to no (unconditionally) have an `#include <omp.h>` as OpenMP can be optional, esp. on macOS.  A simpled `#ifdef OPENMP` does the job.

Second, the (arguably near-incomprehensible) compiler message had to do with the fact that the Boost type / class for `tokenizer` was puzzled by the *Rcpp* object you gave it by directly indexing from an `Rcpp::CharacterVector`. Been there, done that -- a more conservative approach is to *first* assign to `std::string` and to *then* pass that on.

With those two changes, it's all roses and it compiles on macOS under `clang++` as well.

The (by now merged, thanks) [PR #2](https://github.com/seunglee98/fedmatch/pull/2) has the gory details, but is short.